# Rails: assign values to array elements in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a nested form for uploading photos of user.

```
          <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
                 <%= image_tag photo.object.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => "foodio_photo" unless f.object.new_record? or photo.object.new_record? %>
                 <%= photo.file_field :avatar, :style => "none" %>
          <% end %>
           <%= f.link_to_add 'Add Photos', :photos,
                     "data-association-insertion-node"=> ".photos",
                     "data-association-insertion-position" => "append",
                     "data-type" => "link", :class => "subcatlink"%>
```

Using this i can upload multiple photos and first, second etc photos can be accessed. But here i want to upload as photos.first and photo.second instead of access.

Something like:

```
          <%= f.fields_for :photos.first do |photo| %>
                 <%= image_tag photo.object.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => "foodio_photo" unless f.object.new_record? or photo.object.new_record? %>
                 <%= photo.file_field :avatar, :style => "none" %>
          <% end %>
          <%= f.fields_for :photos.second do |photo| %>
                 <%= image_tag photo.object.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => "foodio_photo" unless f.object.new_record? or photo.object.new_record? %>
                 <%= photo.file_field :avatar, :style => "none" %>
          <% end %>
```

But it is not working. gives error of

```
  undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anybody tell how to do it?

Comment: you'll have to create new photos[0] and photos[1] objects in your action that loads this form

Comment: but when i add this: <%= f.link_to_add 'Add Photos', :photos,   "data-association-insertion-node"=> ".photos", "data-association-insertion-position" => "append", "data-type" => "link" %>. It adds multiple photos, which can be accessed with photos.first or photos.second. How to get this separately instead of in loop? Updated question too.

Comment: do you want to restrict uploading one photo at a time? m not really following your question